# Story about a precious bottle of wine; owner waiting for the perfect occasion

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

A wonderful story about a man who owns a bottle of luxury wine and waiting for an important occasion to open the bottle, at the end the bottle is lost and drank by a homeless man does who not know its value.
can you please help me?

Comment: Could you add a few more details about the story? For example, when you read it (since it must be older than that date/year)? In which language it was written or in which language you read it?